# How to enable CORS in this BOTTLE derivated class

Tags: python, cors, bottle, mininet

My REST Api will serve only in localhost, it use this bottle code:

```
https://github.com/cgiraldo/mininetRest/blob/master/mininet_rest.py
```

Firefox/Chrome blocks Cross-Origin Request. I have to enable CORS to let the server deliver an access control response header.

Code example:

```
class MininetRest(Bottle):

def __init__(self, net):
    super(MininetRest, self).__init__()
    self.net = net
    self.route('/pingall', method='GET', callback=self.pingall)

#how to integrate this in my code?
@hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization, Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With'

def pingall(self):
    self.net.pingAll()
```

I have found many codes enabling Cors in Bottle, but no one treated a derived class of the bottle class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below approach?

I've created an utility with EnableCors class like below

```
from bottle import request, response
class EnableCors(object):
    def apply(self, fn, context):
        def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
            # set CORS headers
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE'
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization, Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With'

            if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                # actual request; reply with the actual response
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return _enable_cors
```

and to use it (lets take your class),

```
from path.to.your_utility import EnableCors
class MininetRest(Bottle):
    def __init__(self, net):
        super(MininetRest, self).__init__()
        self.route('/pingall', method='GET', callback=self.pingall)
        self.install(EnableCors())
```

Of course you need to look into the **Access-Control-*** options and chose what is needed for your requirements.

*Hope this helps*

Comment: Gives error (I am using the last Bottle version)
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api/cors.py", line 13, in _enable_cors
    if bottle.request.method != 'OPTIONS':
NameError: global name 'bottle' is not defined`